# Get error message from ctypes windll

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, ctypes

I'm trying to use a Python script to change the wallpaper on a windows 7 computer. If it matters, I'm invoking the script from a node-webkit application.

The shortened script looks as follows:

```
# ...
result = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(20, 0, path, 0)
```

Often, it works, but sometimes, seemingly randomly, it does not. Is there any way for me to retrieve more info about the error than the status code (0 or 1)?

I've been trying to use GetLastError which is sometimes mentioned in relation to the ctypes library, but have been unable to extract any error information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ctypes documentation recommends using `use_last_error=True` to capture `GetLastError()` in a safe way.  Note you need to retrieve the error code when raising `WinError`:

```
from ctypes import *

SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x0014
SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 2
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1

def errcheck(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise WinError(get_last_error())

user32 = WinDLL('user32',use_last_error=True)
SystemParametersInfo = user32.SystemParametersInfoW
SystemParametersInfo.argtypes = [c_uint,c_uint,c_void_p,c_uint]
SystemParametersInfo.restype = c_int
SystemParametersInfo.errcheck = errcheck

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r'xxx',SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,0,r'c:\xxx',SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
  File "C:\test.py", line 9, in errcheck
    raise WinError(get_last_error())
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

An alternative to all this work is to use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files) and call `win32gui.SystemsParametersInfo`.

Comment: `use_last_error` is useful on the main thread if there's a chance the interpreter might execute an interrupt handler that changes the Win32 thread's `LastErrorValue`. This is rare in practice, so I don't usually stress using this feature; maybe I should.

Comment: Robin never got back with me, but I think the issue was simply that it wasn't updating the registry and broadcasting a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.

Comment: At first I thought this worked, but I am unfortunately unable to get it to change my wallpaper at all, even with files that work with my original and modified scripts. I receive the same error, that the system cannot find the file, regardless of what string I input as the third parameter.

Comment: I tested it on 64-bit Windows 7. It would be interesting to know your exact conditions of failure. Oh, and I used 64-bit Python 3. I just noticed your Python 2.7 tag. Are you using 32- or 64-bit Python?

Comment: @Robin, when I try to use a PNG instead of JPG/BMP I get no error at all, even though the call fails. (See my comment on your answer for more details.) Are you sure you're seeing a Win32 error code of 2 in this case? To be sure, call `ctypes.set_last_error(0)` beforehand. That said, using `use_last_error` is probably unnecessary. There should be no Win32 calls on the path back from the FFI call that would modify the thread's `LastErrorValue`, so it's only addressing the possibility of a Win32 call in a signal handler or due to object deallocation. It's a good practice, all the same.

Comment: @Robin, @eryksun, If I use `raise WinError()` in the above code I get `The operation completed successfully` even though the file doesn't exist.  This seems like a case where using `use_last_error` and retrieving the error code through `get_last_error` is called for.

Comment: @Robin, regarding that the above code didn't work for you.  I tested with Python 2 and 3, 32- and 64-bit and it worked (with a `.JPG`).  One thing to check is make sure if you use `SystemParametersInfoW` then pass a Unicode string, and `SystemParametersInfoA` requires a byte string.  with `c_void_p` as the third parameter it won't check that you have it right.  Or change `c_void_p` to `c_char_p` or `c_wchar_p` as appropriate to force the check.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, when raising simply `WinError()`, are you still using `user32 = WinDLL('user32',use_last_error=True)`? That would explain the value of 0. The ctypes thread-local error value gets swapped with the Win32 thread `LastErrorValue` both [before and after the call](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b4cbecbc0781/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.c#l800) (lines 801-805 and 820-824). Thus the error value you'd see would actually be from before the call. To test this try `kernel32.SetLastError(1234);` `user32.SystemParametersInfo(...)`.

Comment: @eryksun, Yes, that was it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen It worked when I converted my path to unicode. Thanks again, both of you.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the wallpaper to an existing file with an unsupported format you receive "The operation completed successfully" even though the wallpaper was not set.

Here is the code I used, which throws an error if you enter a path which does not exist. The function does not throw an error if the file exists, but the format is unsupported.

```
import ctypes, os, sys
from ctypes import WinError, c_int, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import BOOL, HWND, LPCSTR, UINT

path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[1]))

SPIF_SENDCHANGE = 2
SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 1

prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(BOOL, UINT, UINT, LPCSTR, UINT)
paramflags = (1, "SPI", 20), (1, "zero", 0), (1, "path", "test"), (1, "flags", 0)
SetWallpaperHandle = prototype(("SystemParametersInfoA", windll.user32), paramflags)
def errcheck (result, func, args):
    if result == 0:
        raise WinError()
    return result

SetWallpaperHandle.errcheck = errcheck 
try:
    i = SetWallpaperHandle(path=str(path), flags=(SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDCHANGE))
    print(i)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I solved the problem by converting images to .jpg before setting them as a wallpaper.

Comment: The error message is however completely useless, it prints. "[Error 0] The operation completed successfully." So I'm looking for other avenues of locating the error, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: I'm using it on 64-bit windows, without any problemens except the message being useless. However, I'm trying to rewrite it using a function prototype, but so far no luck. I'll get back to you if I have any success. Thanks for taking the time to try to help!

Comment: Made it work with the prototype as well, error message is still "[Error 0] The operation completed successfully." though! I figure I'll test on a few different machines and see if I always get the same outcome. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I attached a debugger to inspect what happens when trying to set a PNG instead of JPG/BMP. It turns out that the system call `user32!NtUserSystemParametersInfo` returns with the `NTSTATUS` code set to 0 (success) even though it obviously failed. In this case there really is no way to know that this call failed somewhere deep in kernel mode (win32k.sys).