# CTypes, raising python-style exception from wrapper

Tags: python, ctypes

In patching the `__rshift__` operator of primitive python types with a callable, the patching utilises a wrapper:

```py
def _patch_rshift(py_class, func):
    assert isinstance(func, FunctionType)

    py_type_name = 'tp_as_number'
    py_type_method = 'nb_rshift'

    py_obj = PyTypeObject.from_address(id(py_class))
    type_ptr = getattr(py_obj, py_type_name)

    if not type_ptr:
        tp_as_obj = PyNumberMethods()
        FUNC_INDIRECTION_REFS[(py_class, '__rshift__')] = tp_as_obj
        tp_as_new_ptr = ctypes.cast(ctypes.addressof(tp_as_obj),
                                    ctypes.POINTER(PyNumberMethods))
        setattr(py_obj, py_type_name, tp_as_new_ptr)

    type_head = type_ptr[0]
    c_func_t = binary_func_p

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except BaseException as be:
            # Need to raise a python style error here:
            wrapper.exc_info = sys.exc_info()
            return False

    c_func = c_func_t(wrapper)
    C_FUNC_CALLBACK_REFS[(py_class, '__rshift__')] = c_func

    setattr(type_head, py_type_method, c_func)
```

The challenge is now to, once an Exception is caught inside `wrapper` to raise an exception here just as any normal python exception.

Raising like:

```py
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except BaseException as be:
            raise
```

or not catching at all:

```py
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Yields:

```sh
Windows fatal exception: access violation
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The desired behavior is to simply re-raise the caught exception, but with a python-style output, if possible.

Related answers rely on the platform being Windows-centered to achieve the desired outcome, which is not suitable, do not preserve the original exception, or do not achieve the desired python exception-style behaviour:

[Get error message from ctypes windll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29847679/7889795)

[Ctypes catching exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175753/ctypes-catching-exception)

UPDATE:

After some more digging, it would appear that raising anywhere in this method triggers a segfault. None the wiser on how to solve it.

Comment: That's not from the wrapper. It's a crash. That can't be caught from code.

Comment: Thanks @CristiFati
While I am aware of it being a crash, I find it interesting that it will only crash if you try and raise an exception there, not raising an exception and for instance passing on catch will have the program continue, albeit in an invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a solution, but a workaround:**

Manually collecting the error information (Using `traceback` and `inspect`), printing to `sys.stderr`, and then returning a pointer to a CTypes error singleton (As done in [forbiddenfruit](https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit)) prevents the segfault from occuring.

The output would then be:

- Custom error code
- Python error code as one would expect from the un-patched primitive

(For brevity, some of the methods used here are not included as they do not add any value to the solution, I opted for a pytest style error format.)

```py
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except BaseException as be:
            # Traceback will not help use here, assemble a custom error message:
            from custom_inspect_utils import get_calling_expression_recursively
            import sys
            calling_file, calling_expression = get_calling_expression_recursively()

            indentation = " "*(len(calling_expression)-len(calling_expression.lstrip()))

            print(f"\n{calling_file}\n>{calling_expression}E{indentation}{type(be).__name__}: {be}", file=sys.stderr)
            print(f"\n\tAs this package patches primitive types, the python RTE also raised:", file=sys.stderr)
            return ErrorSingleton
```

e.g. After patching `list` to implement `__rshift__`, the expression `[1,2,3] >> wrong_target` where one expects a `CustomException` will now first output

```sh
source_file.py:330 (method_name)
>    [1,2,3] >> wrong_target
E    CustomException: Message.
```

followed by a `TypeError`:

```sh
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for >>: 'list' and 'WrongType'
```